Как создать счетчик новых за определенное время постов в блоге Wordpress
Собственно вопрос как оздать счетчик новых за определенное время (за час или за день) постов в блоге Wordpress. Чтобы можно было расположить его в меню сайта.
Заранее большое спасибо :)
Я нашла вот такой код, как я понимаю его нужно розположить в файле functions.php но я не понимаю как добавить отображения самого счетчика в меню.
$posts= get_posts(array(
            'numberposts' => -1,
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'orderby' => 'date',
            'order'   => 'DESC',
            'date_query'    => array(
                'column'  => 'post_date',
                'after'   => '-7 days'  // -7 Means last 7 days 
            )
        ));

Когда я добавляю в меню такой код то он всегда показивает 0:
<h3>Post Count: <?php echo count($posts); ?></h3>


Вам необходимо делать вызов метода в том же месте(области видимости), в котором находятся запрашемые данные.
Если вы, предположим, вызываете это в области меню, и меню находиться у вас в файле head.php, то и вызов должен так же делаться
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>Menu Item 1</li>
    ...
    <?php $posts= get_posts(array(
            'numberposts' => -1,
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'orderby' => 'date',
            'order'   => 'DESC',
            'date_query'    => array(
                'column'  => 'post_date',
                'after'   => '-7 days'  // -7 Means last 7 days 
            )
        )); 
     ?><li><h3>Post Count: <?php echo count($posts); ?></h3></li>
   </ul>
</nav>



Спасибо вам огромное!

Такой вопрос, когда я вставляю код в header.php у меня на любой созданной странице даже пустой отображается последняя опубликования статья из блога. Это сам код с изъяном или я что-то не так делаю?

Надо смотреть код. Так сложно сказать.
